# Using pfctl on Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan) to forward ports

Tags: macos, apache, vagrant, portforwarding, osx-elcapitan

I am currently testing if my developing environment will run on the new upcoming Mac OS 10.11 and if I can upgrade as soon as it's released. On my test machine I am currently running the Beta Preview 3. Everything seems to be running fine.

I just can get `pfctl` to forward my ports. I use Vagrant and Parallels Desktop to run a Debian system for my local web server. Vagrant forwards port 8080 on the host to 80 on the guest. So `127.0.0.1:8080` works fine. But in some projects I want to have the exact same domain local as it will be in production. (without the :8080) Also I just like it more. ;-)

To do that I use `pfctl` to forward 80 to 8080 on the host. Here are my config files:

*~/port-forwarding/pf.conf*

```
rdr-anchor "forwarding"
load anchor "forwarding" from "/Users/nick/port-forwarding/rules.conf"
```

*~/port-forwarding/rules.conf*

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4433
```

To enable it, I run:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf ~/port-forwarding/pf.conf
sudo pfctl -evf ~/port-forwarding/pf.conf
```

This gives me this:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

rdr-anchor "forwarding" all

Loading anchor forwarding from /Users/nick/port-forwarding/rules.conf
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4433
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
rdr-anchor "forwarding" all

Loading anchor forwarding from /Users/nick/port-forwarding/rules.conf
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4433
pf enabled
logout
Saving session...completed.
```

*sudo pfctl -s nat* says:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
rdr-anchor "forwarding" all
```

So far it looks good, I think. But it just does not work.

`127.0.0.1:80` - no connection
`127.0.0.1:8080` - works

I use the same files on Yosemite and it works fine there.

Does anyone know if there's been a change on how to use `pfctl` or if I am doing something wrong or if there's a bug which can be reported.

Thanks a lot

Nick

Comment: Someone asked about it on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/938999/osx-10-11-el-capitan-beta-pf-conf-behaviour-changed) and [this comment](http://superuser.com/questions/938999/osx-10-11-el-capitan-beta-pf-conf-behaviour-changed#comment1281706_938999) in particular might help if you are willing to change the ports you are forwarding to.
You may want to follow the post anyway, as it belongs there more than on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This only applies to OSX 10.11 - El Capitan - Public Beta 1**

x-post from:  https://superuser.com/questions/938999/osx-10-11-el-capitan-beta-pf-conf-behaviour-changed/943981#943981

In the latest 10.11 beta, 127.0.0.1 is blocked.  The solution?  Use 127.0.0.2.  To do this:

First add 127.0.0.2 to the loopback alias
`sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up`

Modify your pf rule to use the the new alias.
`rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.2 port 8080`

From the command line, without using a file:

`echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {80,8080} -> 127.0.0.2 port 8080" | pfctl -Ef -`  <-- Be sure to add this last tick, you're piping in STDIN)

Comment: I just upgrades to 10.11 Beta 4 and it seems to be working as it did before.

Comment: make sure you use sudo:

`echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {80,8080} -> 127.0.0.2 port 8080" | sudo pfctl -Ef -`

Comment: Just as a note for others looking, 127.0.0.1 does not appear to be blocked within the public release versions of El Capitan, for example on OS X 10.11.5. I have been able to successfully setup `pf`-based local loopback forwarding against 127.0.0.1 on El Capitan.