# Using pfctl to redirect traffic does not work

Tags: macos, networking, proxy, mitmproxy, burp

I am trying to set up a proxy on OSX to intercept traffic. I found that the native way to do it is using [pfctl](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html) and using a transparent proxy tool like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) or [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/). Mitmproxy has a chapter in their [docs](https://www.appsecconsulting.com/blog/running-stubborn-devices-through-burp-suite-via-osx-mountain-lion-and-above) about how to set up the Mac with pfctl and for Burp Suite you can find this [instruction](https://www.appsecconsulting.com/blog/running-stubborn-devices-through-burp-suite-via-osx-mountain-lion-and-above). However, none of these are showing traffic in mitmproxy or burp.

My /etc/pf.conf

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "forwarding"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "forwarding" from "/etc/pf.anchors/forwarding"
```

and my /etc/pf.anchors/forwarding (en0 is my working wifi adapter)

```
rdr log (all) on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr log (all) on en0 inet proto tcp to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
```

I am also setting

```
▶ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
▶ sudo sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
```

and these commands work without throwing an error

```
▶ sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
▶ sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517368/using-pfctl-on-mac-os-10-11-el-capitan-to-forward-ports) is another related question, but as I am on Sierra, the answer does not apply to me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've run into a similar issue on MacOS Mojave (10.14) - I'm trying to port forward SSH traffic from my ethernet adapter to a networked machine on a different adapter.

echo "rdr pass inet proto { tcp, udp } from any to any port 2222 -> 192.168.1.64 port 22" | sudo pfctl -ef -

Can't seem to get any traffic through either!

Comment: Oof, sorry I don't remember at all..