# local port forward to wlan ip address on MacOS

Tags: macos, port, portforwarding, netstat

Env

OS OSX 13.6

`nc localhost 4444`

`netstat -R -P tcp  -v -a -n  | grep 4444`

`tcp6       0      0  ::1.4444               *.*                    LISTEN               0          0 131072 131072   1375      0`

First I use pfctl to achieve it

The solution to this problem is in the link below on OSX 10.11
[Using pfctl on Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan) to forward ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517368/using-pfctl-on-mac-os-10-11-el-capitan-to-forward-ports)

And other solution in `/etc/pf.conf` ,No thing changed

This is not suitable for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Env

```sh
server: nc -l 127.0.0.1 4444
client： nc 192.168.0.99 8088
```

The tempary  solution is

```sh
sudo pfctl -F all

sudo echo "rdr pass  proto tcp from any to any port 8088 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4444" | sudo pfctl -Ef -

sudo pfctl -s nat
```

#### Atention

> chose `127.0.0.1` not `localhost`